# regex with wildcards in the middle of a string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, wildcard

I have a bounch of registry exports from [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections] from different users.
This files contain multiple lines with "

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\,,BBPRINTER01.domain.local,AG-printer-S4]
```

from which I need the `BBPRINTER01.domain.local,AG-printer-S4` part. Problem is, the `BBPRINTER01` and `AG-printer-S4` can differe.

So I would need a regex, which extracts "*.domain.local,*" from `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\,,BBPRINTER01.domain.local,AG-printer-S4]`.

And I don`t have any clue, to generate this :(

with `(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])` I can get everything including the `[]` but I don`t know how to get only the wildcard string from above.

Comment: The question is not totally clear, do you want to find all the possible values inside the square brakets after `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\` ? So for exmple with [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\,,A,B] the string 'A,B' ?

Comment: @Panciz It is crystal clear: the value OP seeks is between brackets, at the end, starting with some word chars and `.domain.local` up to closing `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to parse this from several files in a folder, you can use

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\The\Files' -File
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | 
    Select-String -Pattern '\[.*,([^,]+,[^\]]+)\]' -AllMatches | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
}
```

Regex details

```
\[              Match the character “[” literally
    .           Match any single character
   *            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
,               Match the character “,” literally
(               Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^,]         Match any character that is NOT a “,”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ,            Match the character “,” literally
   [^\]]        Match any character that is NOT a “]”
      +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)              
\]              Match the character “]” literally
```

Result could be something like

```
BBPRINTER01.domain.local,AG-printer-S4
BBPRINTER02.otherdomain.local,AG-printer-S5
BBPRINTER03.somedomain.local,AG-printer-S6
```

---

**Edit**

As per your comment, to output both the file path and the regex match, the cleanest way would be to output **objects** instead of strings and capture these results in a variable. Using objects, you also have the opportunity to write to a structured CSV file you can open in Excel:

```
$files  = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\The\Files' -File
$result = foreach ($file in $files) {
    Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | 
    Select-String -Pattern '\[.*,([^,]+,[^\]]+)\]' -AllMatches | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'SourceFile'   = $file.FullName
            'Regex-Output' = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value 
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\result.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I marked the correct answer; one last question, how do I the output from "ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value | Out-File $Results -Append}" that I get something like "sourcefilename,regex-output" in the results file?
at the moment I only get the "regex-output" line per line in the results file;

Comment: @horst Thanks. Please see my edit which should give you an idea of how you can output to an array of objects

Comment: worked quite well! many many thx again for your Help!

Comment: I changed the "'SourceFile'   = $file.FullName" to "'SourceFile'   = $file.BaseName" because I only the plain filename in the output file, without the full path and the file extension;

Comment: @horst You can set any property you need in there. I just wasn't sure if you wanted the full path or just the name of the file, but you figured that out yourself. Well done ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may capture the substring into Group 1 using

```bsh
\[[^][]*?(\w+\.domain\.local,[^][]*)]
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%3f%28%5cw%2b%5c.domain%5c.local%2c%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%29%5d&i=%5bHKEY_CURRENT_USER%5cPrinters%5cConnections%5c%2c%2cBBPRINTER01.domain.local%2cAG-printer-S4%5d). It matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]*?` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` as few as possible
- `(` - start of the Capturing group 1
- `\w+` - one or more letters/digits/`_`
- `\.domain\.local,` - a `.domain.local,` string
- `[^\]\[]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `)` end of the capturing group
- `]` - a `]` char.

In PowerShell, use

```bsh
$result = Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern '\w+\.domain\.local,[^][]*'
if ($result.Matches.Success) { $result.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
# => BBPRINTER01.domain.local,AG-printer-S4
```

PowerShell test:

[image]

Comment: many thx, the pattern works in the tester quite well!
but when I try to call the pattern via
Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern '\w+\.domain\.local,[^\]\[]*' | select -Expand Line
I get the whole string between [] and not only the filtered one

Comment: @horst You need to assign the result to a variable that will be of type `MatchInfo`, then, all you need is to access its Group 1 value. I updated the answer.

Comment: something seems not to be correct with the new regex string anymore, because I don`t get any results in the regex test anymore and the powershell gives me ths result:

+     $result.Matches.Groups[1].Value
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: @horst See the screenshot. It seems like you do not have any match in the file you specified.

Comment: I think the problem is, that I´m calling the funktion in an forearch loop, becaus I have many files, I`d like to Parse:
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $result = Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern '\[[^][]*?(\w+\.domain\.local,[^][]*)]'
    $result.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}

Comment: @horst Ok, so no action is necessary if there is no match, right? Check if the match is a `Success`, and then print the value, see updated answer.